# How to migrate AngularJS project to React Native Project

Tags: angularjs, react-native

We have built huge **SAAS** platform with **AngularJS** about **8** years ago, now our team decided to update framework from **AngularJS** to **React**

Is there any tool, or strategy, or advises to migrate without too much writing coding ?